# Changing data type from character to Date in r

Tags: r, types, character, posixct

hi guys im working on this project, and i stumble across this problem. so the original data type for this data is character and im trying to convert it to date.

[image]

I managed to change it using `as.Date`, however, if I use that, I lose the hours and minutes details. but then I use `as.POSIXct` and I got NA in return. I've tried every format yet I keep running into the same problem.

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime characters does not include seconds:

```
lubridate::parse_date_time("12/31/2006 13:37", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
#> [1] "2006-12-31 13:37:00 UTC"
```